# 'Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier' only on Device

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have this storyboard :

[image]

With this ViewController :

[image]

I have this code to instanciate my VC :

```
let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_iPhone", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("POIListViewController")
```

When i'm running on simulator, everything works thine.

But when i launch on real device, i have this exception :

```
2016-07-12 10:56:19.073 App-Ely[1935:562264] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x185481b0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'POIListViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2a23b5f7 0x37aadc77 0x2dc36f25 0x182b8c 0x182dd0 0x12d99f 0x2a1f3f15 0x2a14ee4d 0x2ae83ec1 0x13e0d5 0x168a2d 0x2d7f9607 0x2d8ab0a7 0x2d75d1f1 0x2d6d8eff 0x2a202015 0x2a1ff6f9 0x2a1ffafb 0x2a14cb31 0x2a14c943 0x3152c051 0x2d7426f1 0x16fce3 0x38049aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

> EDIT :

I have my storyboard correctly loaded :

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_iPhone", bundle: nil)
    // 'storyboardName' contains "Main_iPhone"
    let storyboardName : String = storyboard.valueForKey("name") as! String
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("POIListViewController")
```

Comment: Could you try this code? if let vc: POIListViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("POIListViewController") as? POIListViewController {
    //Your code
}

Comment: nop, it's the same

Comment: @Imbru Hi. On which real device do you run the project?

Comment: @Mozilla Hi, on 4s (iOS 8) and 6s (last iOS version)

Comment: Can you check the VC is still visible as an IB connection when you select a phone size class in the storyboard?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_iPhone", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("POIListViewController") as! UIViewController
```

**EDIT**

Just CLEAN your project (CMD+SHIFT+K) as you have change the storyboard name I think.

Comment: check you are getting storyboard object or not.

Comment: I have check with your code and i have the storyboard into var storyboard

Comment: what you are getting in vc ?

Comment: In my simulator, i have a view controller into 'vc' var

Comment: still you are getting crash?

Comment: always crashing, but only on real device, not on simulator

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it to :

```
let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("POIListViewController") as! POIListViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your project and open it again.
If you noticed the identifier is gone, then it must be a problem of auto-saving.
Simply save your storyboard file after putting your new identifier.
and Clean-Build-Run.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (except it wasn't only on device).

None of the previous suggestions in this thread worked for me. What worked was going to the Identity Inspector (in right hand Utilities Pane), and making sure the Storyboard ID field was also populated with the View Controller name (same name as the Class field above it).

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem because of a copy of the localization file. Perhaps the simulator includes English, but this gadget has its own language.
See if you have a storyboard with two localization files?